# Отладка программы в Линуксе

Tags: linux, c, linux-mint, vim, clang

Программирую на линуксе, язык `С`. Пользуюсь редактором `vim` и компилятором `clang`. Хочу узнать какие есть проги для отладки на линуксе (до этого юзал только `valgrind` для поиска утечек памяти). К примеру: прога вылетает и сообщает об ошибке сигментации - как эффективно отладить эту ошибку на линуксе, какие проги для этого понадобятся?

Comment: gdb наше всё...

Comment: Дебаггер в LLVM (Clang) - LLDB.

Comment: *оффтоп*. Боюсь спросить глупость, но все же. В сторону ide смотрели? В хорошей будет поддерживаться отладчик, валгринд, контроль версий, статический анализ, инструменты рефакторинга и еще черт знает что.

Comment: ага, конечно:) отладчик? кое-как. валгринд? qtcreator, и тот через пень-колоду. контроль версий? дифы/блейм смотреть, но консоль надежнее, статический анализ? qtcreator пытается, clion без телодвижений даже не заводит, рефакторинг... о тут все весело, особенно с макросами

Comment: @KoVadim, Ну вы палку-то не преувеличивайте. На прошлой неделе надо было немного поработать с CMake проектом. Скачивание, установка и настройка Qt Creator заняли в сумме пол часа. valgringd, gdb, git clang code model работают из коробки. Вся настройка свелась к выбору приятных шрифтов и расцветки

Comment: не поймите меня неправильно. В маленьких проектах на два с половиной файла все работает более-менее ожидаемо и хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim, ИМХО, 80к строк это не так уж и мало. Да и не думаю что у автора такое адское спагетти из макросов, скриптов и автогенерации, чтоб современные ide его не перварили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

простой способ поиска.

- программу компилируем с отладочной информацией (`-g` или `-ggdb`)
- открываем в  отладчике gdb ./бинарь
- запускаем (уже внутри отладчика) `run` или `run arg1 arg2 ..`
- ждем падения, попутно по надобности взаимодействуем с программой
- когда упало, пишем bt, обычно этого уже хватает, что бы понять причину.

Что делать, если причина не до конца понятна? в стектрейсе напротив каждой строки есть число - это номер фрейма. Выбираем понятный нам фрейм и переключаемся на него - `frame <число>`. Теперь, используя `print <имя переменной>` можно вывести себе побольше данных.

Если gdb нет, можно посмотреть, доступен ли lldb. Команды у него такие же (для данного описания).

если приложение многопоточное, то возможно лучше написать `bt all`, что бы смотреть стеки всех потоков, а не только того, который упал.

Answer (score 1):

LLDB is a next generation, high-performance debugger. It is built as a set of reusable components which highly leverage existing libraries in the larger LLVM Project, such as the Clang expression parser and LLVM disassembler.

LLDB is the default debugger in Xcode on Mac OS X and supports debugging C, Objective-C and C++ on the desktop and iOS devices and simulator.

https://lldb.llvm.org/